# Passar array multidimensional para php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou lutando com um problema a dias..

É o seguinte, tenho um array multidimensional e quero passar como parâmetro em uma requisão *ajax* para um arquivo php , porem quando estou fazendo isso o que está me retornando é um vazio do php. Não tenho ideia do por que , pesquisei e não encontrei nada que correspondesse a minha dúvida.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz!

Segue os codigos!

```
// Criando o array global
var dados = new Array();
dados[contador] = new Array();
dados[contador]['usuarios'];
dados[contador]['quantidade'];
```

`var usuario = false;
  //Verificando se usuario já existe
   for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
       if (dados[i]['usuarios'] === usuarioDivisao) {
           dados[i]['usuarios'] = usuarioDivisao;
           dados[i]['quantidade'] = $("input[name='mailing_quantididade_html']").val();
           usuario = true;
           break;
           }
       }
    if (!usuario) {
     dados[contador] = new Array();
     dados[contador]['quantidade'] = $("input[name='mailing_quantididade_html']").val();
     dados[contador]['usuarios'] = usuarioDivisao;
     contador++;
   }
                $("input[name='mailing_quantididade_html']").val("");`

Depois de popula-los estou passando como parâmetro para o arquivo php

```
$('.atualizar').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Mailing/exportar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {dados:  JSON.stringify(dados), caminho: 'MailingTemp/qualquernomeOcidental2.csv', usuario: usuarioDivisao},
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".mailing #aguarde_pequena2").fadeOut(200);
            $(".mailing #aguarde_pequena").fadeIn(200);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tenta setar o tipo de dados que você está passando no ajax: dataType: 'json'

Comment: Tenta enviar diretamente como um array, sem usar o `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Cara se vc quer pegar via `$_POST` no php tem de passar os valores com aspas no js. Ex: `{"dados": dados, "caminho":caminho}`

Comment: Eu tentei tudo o que vocês falaram , mas nao deu , valeu! Mas eu dei um alert no array e ele está vindo vazio antes de passar para requisão ajax, será que o problema pode ser esse ? Ele está mandando para o php um array vazio, mas ele preenche normal, só na hora de enviar ele esta aparecendo vazio.. Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Periotto, eu ja fiz isso antes com um array simples , a diferença agora que esse array é mais complexo. Eu estou pegando com o ```GetPost```, estou fazendo assim no php: ```$arrayDados = json_decode(stripslashes(GetPost('dados')));```

Comment: Mostra o todo o código onde vc monta o array(for, while, etc)

Comment: Beleza , vou editar a pergunta!

Comment: Cara vc esta usando `dados.lenght`.O `for` nunca vai ser executado pq nao existe nenhum registro no array

Comment: Justamente , se não existir nenhum registro no array e ele adiciona , se não ele substitui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você usar um índice string, ao acessar um array, JavaScript irá redefinir a matriz para um objeto padrão, e todos os métodos e propriedades de Array irá produzir resultados indefinidos ou incorretos.

Veja:

```
var dados[0] = new Array();
dados[0] = new Array();
dados[0]['usuarios']; // neste momento dados[0] passa a ser um objeto do js
//para acessar o dado use: dados[0].usuarios;
//JSON.stringfy(dados); retornará "[[]]" por causa da despadronização do array
```

Você pode montar seu array assim por exemplo:

```
var dados[0] = new Array()
dados[0] = {usuarios:0, quantidade:0};
dados[1] = {usuarios:1, quantidade:1};
```

Ajax:

```
$('.atualizar').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Mailing/exportar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {dados:  JSON.stringify(dados), caminho: 'MailingTemp/qualquernomeOcidental2.csv', usuario: usuarioDivisao},
        dataType: 'json', //Lembrado pelo Luis Henrique
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".mailing #aguarde_pequena2").fadeOut(200);
            $(".mailing #aguarde_pequena").fadeIn(200);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

No PHP:

```
$arrDados = json_decode($_POST['dados']);
```

Comment: Assim, muito obrigado pelo toque! So que isso muda minha função inteira , como eu não sabia disso ai fiquei meio confuso.. Como eu vou passar um valor para esse array ? Por exemplo: eu estava fazendo assim  `dados[contador]['usuarios'] = usuarioDivisao;`, como vou fazer agora ?

Comment: //Mais ou menos assim @MarlonCastro
var dados = new Array();
var input = $("input[name='mailing_quantididade_html']");
dados[contador] = {usuarios : 0, quantidade:0};

 var usuario = false;
   for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
       if (dados[i].usuarios === usuarioDivisao) {
           dados[i].usuarios = usuarioDivisao;
           dados[i].quantidade = input.val();
           usuario = true;
           break;
           }
       }
    if (!usuario) {
      dados[contador] = {
     usuarios: input.val(), 
     quantidade: usuarioDivisao
   }
     contador++;
   }
   input.val("");

Comment: Isso ai , valeu @DougladeSouza.. So estou com probleminha para acessar essa matriz no php , mas o primeiro passo foi dado! Valeu!